# .NET Security - Adding a new user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using this in c# MVC. I am creating a registration screen for the user with the following fields

```
   UserName,Password,Role,Location
```

The **Role** can be either "Admin" or "User".

The **Location**, it can be either "New York" or "Chicago".

Once the user fills out the form and clicks on Submit, I have the following code:

```
     .....
     .....
     MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
     Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, null, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

    if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
    {
       FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
       Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, model.Role);
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

I have taken care of Creating the user and also giving that user a role as you can see above. I am not sure how to tie the Location with the User and Role though. What aspnet table would Location go into? Is there a method that already handles something like this?

Comment: Is the location used to identify the user? Can I create a Nate in New York and a second Nate in Chicago?

Comment: Yes you can create a Nate in New York and a Nate in Chicago? I am assuming it should be tied to the UserId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: You can use built-in [ASP.NET Profile](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281602/ASP-NET-Profile-Provider) to store custom user information

2: To be more customized and having more control over data manipulation, you will have to create a separate table to store the additional user details. Something along [these lines](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2009/01/27/storing-user-profile-into-a-custom-table-using-createuser-wizard-control.aspx).

3: IF you think there's only going to be ONLY ONE FIELD FOREVER, a weirdest way is to use [Comment property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.comment.aspx) of MembershipUser. Though not sure how best it fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if you tried #1 in a real application as it does not seem to be working for me. My program cannot recognize what Profile is in Profile.Location = "New York". Note that in my web.config file, I did add     <properties>
        <add name="Location" type="String" />
      </properties> inside of <profile>

Comment: Yes, I have used it. Make sure the ProfileProvider is configured properly in web.config and also make sure you aspnetdb membership database has Aspnet_Profiles table.

Answer (score 0):

If the only extra information you have is the location, then this may be an overkill, but I think your best friend is the profile provider. Take a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can define your own information for a given user.

Comment: "Where there is one field now, there will be many in the future."  I'm pretty sure someone smart said that once.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this may be an overkill. Can you think of any table that I can store this in within the current db structure for Membership, Role?

Comment: One thought I had was to store the Location in the aspnet_Membership table.